# Не стартует служба openvpn на ubuntu16

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

Обычно проблем с установкой сервера openvpn не было.
Сделал все по инструкции этой статьи [настройка](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openvpn-ubuntu-16-04-ru).
Но служба не стартует.

Хотя если запускать в ручную:

```
openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf
```

все работает)

а вот если запускаю как в статье

```
systemctl start openvpn@server
systemctl status openvpn@server
```

получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все починил! помог этот вопрос https://askubuntu.com/questions/747023/systemd-fails-to-start-openvpn-in-lxd-managed-16-04-container

Comment: закомментировал строку LimitNPROC в файле /lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service

Comment: Тогда напиши полный листинг в качестве ответа